# Overlapping tables on web page when position set to relative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page with multiple tables, and I'm having an issue where tables are overlapping when you zoom in or out, and are sort of floating all over the place.

My CSS setting is set to `position: relative`, but changing them to `absolute` is also causing overlaps when zooming in.

Comment: `position:relative;` is _intended_ to allow overlap, though whether it will _actually_ overlap in a specific case depends on the other settings. Could you please be a bit more specific about the settings you're using and why you think they shouldn't overlap? "sort of floating all over the place" isn't giving us much to go on with. How is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: What other settings will affect whether or not it overlaps? And setting the position to static or absolute..why is it that things still overlap on zooming in and out?

Answer (score 0):

Position will work properly only if the absolutely positioned element has a parent with relative position.